# How to check all variables are being used in a bash script?

Tags: bash, variables

Is there are way to check that all variables declared in a bash script are being used? Something analogous to -Wall in c++?

Cheers

Comment: That's somewhat tricky, because you can't do it statically.

Answer (score 6):

There's no built-in way to do this, no, and it can never be done perfectly, because of situations like these:

- Suppose the user's Bash profile exports `CLASSPATH` as an environment variable. Then a Bash script might include a statement like

  ```
  CLASSPATH=...
  ```

  but never refer to `CLASSPATH`, if its only purpose in assigning to `CLASSPATH` is to modify the behavior of some program that uses the environment variable (such as `java`).
- Suppose that I create variables `a` and `b`, and a variable `c` whose value is obtained from the user and can be either `a` or `b`. I can then use `${!c}` to obtain the value of the user-specified variable; a given run of the script might never refer to `b` (because `c` is set to `'a'`), but a different run of the script might do differently.

That said, you might be interested in the `-u` option to the `set` builtin. If your script contains this command:

```
set -u
```

then from that point on, it will be an error to refer to a variable or parameter that has not been set. This can help detect typos in variable-names and whatnot. This is obviously much less than what `gcc -Wall` does (since `gcc` *always* gives an error-message when you refer to an undeclared variable), but you may find it beneficial in the same way.

Comment: Thanks, the `set -u` would be useful. However, I'm looking for something that would check all declared variables are being used, not that all variables that are being used are declared. Perhaps a bash script would be able to do this?

Comment: @Eddy: Yes, I understand what you're looking for. As I explained, there's no built-in way to do it, and it can never be done perfectly. Are you looking for an error-prone way to approximate that?